# Android intent exclude a particular file extension?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I want my Activity to be able to open files without any extensions and files with these two extensions: `.ext1` and `.ext2`.

Examples: 
Open: my_file.ext1, my_file.ext2, some_other_file, another_file 
Ignore: my_file.pdf, myfile.mp3, etc.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext1" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext2" />
</intent-filter>
```

How to include the files without any extension and ignore the files with an extension ?

The only solution I found so far to include files without any extension is to also add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:mimeType="text/plain"
        android:scheme="file"
        android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But this also associates my Activity with .txt files. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: No and I think there isn't because you can only tell the filter what you want to include. I just used the solution in my question. The side effect was that my app was listed also when usee tries to open text files. I just check that the file type (the contents of the file) is the one I'm interested in.

Comment: And it works for opening Gmail attachments too?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't even thought about that. Try and let us know.

Comment: For Gmail you would need **android:host="gmail-ls"**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have your app to open files with **NO** extension, is to use `android:mimeType="*/*"`.  Unfortunately, that will make your app open all files on the device too.

For the case of opening **SPECIFIC** file extensions with your app, here what you need:

```
        <!-- Handle opening attachments with file explorer -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="application/json"
                  android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext1"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*"
                  android:mimeType="*/*"
                  android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext1"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="application/json"
                  android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext2"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext2"
                android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Handle opening attachments with Downloads app -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext1"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/json" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext1"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext1"
                  android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext2"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/json" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext2"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\.ext2"
                  android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
```